# Fijar filas o columnas pero de una tabla de Excel

Tags: excel, tablas

Muy buenas tardes estimados. Tengo el siguiente inconveniente. Estoy queriendo aplicar una formula a columnas de una tabla en excel (no a datos en formato tabular, si no a una tabla definida como tal con un nombre como "tabla1"). La cuestión es que quiero arrastrar la formula hacia la derecha y que ciertas referencias a columnas de esa tabla se queden fijas y no estoy pudiendo fijarlas. Lo mismo me pasa si quiero fijar las filas.

Cuando quiero fijar una celda cualquiera la fijo de esta manera:

```
$[columna]$[fila]
```

Mi pregunta es entonces:

¿Cómo puedo hacer lo mismo pero cuando trabajo dentro de una tabla?

Si por ejemplo quisiera hacer algo así (que no está bien por que ya lo probé jaja):

$[Nombre] ==> Fijar la columna "Nombre" en una formula implementada dentro de una tabla

Desde ya muchas gracias. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Lo que tienes que hacer es escribir las celdas a mano en la fórmula y no seleccionarlas con el ratón.

Es decir, si quieres multiplicar la celda A2 por 3 y obtener el resultado en B2 escríbelo tal cual en la fórmula de la celda B2:

```
= $A$2 * 3
```

**No lo hagas seleccionando con el ratón las celdas que intervienen en la fórmula**. Así podrás arrastrar la fórmula.

Para fijar el dato de la columna o de la fila utiliza el símbolo del $.

Comment: Pensé también eso, pero el problema es que mi formula tiene varios SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(), y necesito que algunos rangos considerados por esa formula se adapten dinámicamente, por eso estoy usando una tabla... a menos que haya alguna forma de adaptar un rango dinámicamente sin usar una tabla...¿?

Comment: @geropiedrabuena deberías documentarte sobre referencias relativas, mixtas y absolutas para lo que quieres. En cualquier caso, en una formula seguramente se pueden aplicar lo que llamas rangos dinámicos y rangos fijos